# How do I do x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9?

Tags: java, for-loop

This is just a small part of a much larger problem, but I do need to do this. This has to be done using Java for loops. I only have this so far:

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println(calculateExp(3.0));
}

public static double calculateExp(double x) {
 for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i += 2) { 
         x += x*x;
 }
 return x;
}
```

}

Edit: I also can't use any libraries other than the original, meaning I can't use the easy Math.pow().

Comment: Can you use Math class?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question. To give you a hint. You can use the example from the answer of @Eden Yosef and just write your own Math.pow method.

Comment: Use a nested for loop to calculate the x^i (since you can't use `Math.pow`).

Comment: `return x + x*x*x + x*x*x*x*x + x*x*x*x*x*x*x + x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x;`

Comment: @AndrewS Yeah, I know, and I have a loop for the exponent. But how would you make a loop for the multiply x by itself that many exponent number of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's `Math.pow` will be useful ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-))

You also should not be modifying `x` as you go (since you always want the *same* number raised to varying powers), but rather have a separate variable to collect the sum.

In the end, it should look something like this:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(calculateExp(3.0));
    }

    public static double calculateExp(double x) {
        double total = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i += 2) {
            total += Math.pow(x, i);
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

EDIT: if you're not allowed to use Math.pow, you can calculate `x^i` manually with another loop, like this:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(calculateExp(3.0));
    }

    public static double calculateExp(double x) {
        double total = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i += 2) {
            double x_to_i = 1.0;
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                x_to_i *= x;
            }
            total += x_to_i;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can import java.lang.Math, and then use Math.pow(a, b), the code can look like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double a = 30;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int b = 1; b <= 9; b += 2) { 
        sum += Math.pow(a, b)
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about this. If I could do that, this would be much easier.

Comment: variable `i` is not declared

Comment: yeah i should be b, forgot to change that. updated :D